# SharePoint 2013 list search results intermittent

Tags: custom-list, crawl, crawled-property, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with a multiple line of text column. (Column is rich text enhanced.) Versioning is applied to the list.

When searching in the list itself I am getting intermittent results. All the text within the box in not formatted in any way. It will return a search result if I copy some keywords from the box but then not if I copy others from the box.

I have continious, incremental and full crawled since finding the issue and I have also reindexed the library before each.